# How do i ignore div which style = none with JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, jspdf

i have a situation,in which i have to ignore some divs,  i'am using a JSPDF plugin,
the idea is to get only some div(which are the result of user choices), JSPDF get the code frome html, so it get even the hidden divs.

this is my code, but it's not working, any help will be appreciated,

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

var specialElementHandlers = {

    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {

        return true;
    }

};


     $("div[style*='display:none']").remove();

    doc.fromHTML($('#resultat').html(),15, 15,{
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });




    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");


<div id="resultatConflit" style="display:none">
                    &lt;label><b>Test de Conflit</b>&lt;/label>
                    <div id="TNeer" style="display:none">
                        &lt;label for="cnfl1">Test de Neer &lt;/label>
                        <div id="cnfl1"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ADouloureux" style="display:none">
                        &lt;label for="cnfl2">Arc Douleureux &lt;/label>
                        <div id="cnfl2"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Yowm" style="display:none">
                        &lt;label for="cnfl3">Yowm &lt;/label>
                        <div id="cnfl3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="THKenedy" style="display:none">
                        &lt;label for="cnfl4">Test de Howkins-Kenedy &lt;/label>
                        <div id="cnfl4"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="CATest" style="display:none">
                        &lt;label for="cnfl5">Cross Abduction Test &lt;/label>
                        <div id="cnfl5"></div>
                    </div> .
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `.fromHTML()` does not check your CSS. I have used `.addHtml()` with `style="display:none"` and it worked for me.

Don't use `opacity=0` because the `.pdf` is going to show the `div` in spite of *does not display* in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches, first is faster than second.

1. `var $visibleDivs = $('div').not(':hidden');`
2. `var $visibleDivs = $('div:not(:hidden)');`

In your code `$("div[style*='display:none']")` would only select the hidden divs which are made hidden by inline style attribute & not the ones which are made hidden by css rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need to use the display attribute not visibility, i wonder if there's a solution ..

Comment: Did you try above lines..I am guessing not.. it would have worked.. `:hidden` here is not visibility but display attribute only. check out https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/ 
**`Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.`**